# How can I send a batch of messages to an Azure EventHub? (C# WinForm and .NET 5.0)

Tags: c#, asynchronous, backgroundworker, azure-eventhub

I am building a telemetry simulator to send messages to an Azure EventHub (WinForm, .NET 5.0).

I use backgroundworkers for each telemetry device, the code below is the DoWork method of one of the devices.  The app works fine when I output the messages to the console.

The problem occurs when I add the (commented out) EventHub code shown in the while loop below. There are two issues:

1. Backgroundworker.ReportProgress fails with:  System.InvalidOperationException: 'This operation has already had OperationCompleted called on it and further calls are illegal.'
2. I also can no longer cancel the process (i.e. truckWorker.CancellationPending is always false)

If I uncomment the EventHub code, and comment out truckWorker.ReportProgress(i++), the app works and sends messages to the EventHub. Problem is I still can't cancel the operation and of course I loose my progress indicator.

```
private async void SendTruckMsg(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    EventHubProducerClient evClient = (EventHubProducerClient)e.Argument;
    List<TruckTelemetry> collection = virtualThingsController.GetTruckTelemetry();
    int interval = virtualThingsController.GetTruckTelemetryInterval();
    int i = 0; // count messages sent
 
    while (!truckWorker.CancellationPending)  // ===> can't cancel operation anymore
    {
        //using var eventBatch = await evClient.CreateBatchAsync(); // create batch

        foreach (TruckTelemetry truckTelemetry in collection)
        {
            truckTelemetry.Timestamp = DateTime.Now;
            string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(truckTelemetry);
            
            //eventBatch.TryAdd(new EventData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(output))); // add to batch
        }

        //await evClient.SendAsync(eventBatch); // send the batch

        truckWorker.ReportProgress(i++);

        Thread.Sleep(interval);
    }
}
```

Sending messages could be synchronous but there is no simple 'send' method for the EventHubProducerClient.

Appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: I can't say definitively, but this seems like an issue using async calls with the background worker.  Since your `SendTruckMsg` signature has a `void` return, we know that nothing is awaiting it and is likely assuming it completes synchronously.  When you're calling into Event Hubs, those calls are asynchronous and are most likely happening after the worker believes that `SendTruckMsg` has completed.   I don't think the background worker is suitable for this kind of workload, but if you're set on using it, adding `.ConfigureAwait(false)` to each of your async calls may (or may not) help.

Comment: @Jesse, I think you are correct that is my problem.  What I don't understand is how do I combine 'parallelism' and 'asynchronous' behavior in a single app.  My simulator has six different telemetry generator (e.g. Truck, Train, Ship, etc.) and they are completely independent of each other.  I can start/stop them individually, the message send interval is unique to each of them, etc.  The background worker looked perfect for this multithreaded problem.

Comment: I put some thoughts together in an answer below due to the comment formatting and size limits.  I'd strongly recommend considering the approach there, moving to using tasks for the background operations over the worker.  If you're set on using the background worker, you could force sync-over-async by calling `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` on each async call rather than awaiting it.   The caveat is that opens you to possible threadpool exhaustion and, potentially, deadlocks.   I'd recommend avoiding it if at all possible.

Answer (score 3):

Before I touch on the background processing, there's a couple of things that I'm seeing in your snippet that look like they're likely to be a problem in your application:

- It appears that you're using a `List<TruckTelemetry>` on multiple threads, one that adds items and the background operation that publishes them to Event Hubs.   The list isn't thread-safe.  I'd recommend moving to a [ConcurrentQueue<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1), which is thread-safe and will help preserve the ordering of your telemetry.
- Your snippet is ignoring the return of the `TryAdd` method of the `EventDataBatch` and assuming that every telemetry item in your loop was successfully added to the batch.  This can lead to data loss, as you would be unaware if the batch was full and events were not able to be added.
- Your snippet doesn't handle the corner case where a telemetry item is too large and could never be published to Event Hubs.  Granted, if your telemetry items are tiny, this isn't a case that you're likely to encounter, but I'd recommend including it just to be safe.

With asynchronous operations, the typical approach to working in the background is to start a new `Task` that you can cancel or wait to complete when it makes sense for the application.

If I translate your general scenario, turning it into a task and addressing my feedback, your telemetry processing would look something like:

```cs
public static Task ProcessTruckTelemetry(EventHubProducerClient producer,
                                         VirtualThingsController controller,
                                         CancellationToken cancellationToken,
                                         Action<int> progressCallback) =>
    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        var eventBatch = default(EventDataBatch);
        var totalEventCount = 0;        
        var interval = controller.GetTruckTelemetryInterval();        
        
        // I'm assuming a change to ConcurrentQueue<T> for the
        // the telemetry interactions via the controller.
        
        var telemetryQueue = controller.GetTruckTelemetry();
                
        while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            // In this example, we'll pump the telemetry queue as long
            // long as there are any items in there.  If you wanted to 
            // limit, you could also include a maximum count and stop there.
            
            while ((!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested) 
                && (telemetryQueue.TryPeek(out var telemetry))
            {
                // Create a batch if we don't currently have one.

                eventBatch ??= (await producer.CreateBatchAsync().ConfigureAwait(false));
                
                // Translate the telemetry data.
                
                telemetry.Timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow;                
                var serializedTelemetry = JsonSerializer.Serialize(telemetry);
                var eventData = new EventData(new BinaryData(serializedTelemetry));
                
                // Attempt to add the event to the batch.  If the batch is full, 
                // send it and clear state so that we know to create a new one.
                
                if (!eventBatch.TryAdd(eventData))
                {
                    // If there are no events in the batch, this event is
                    // too large to ever publish.  We can't recover.
                    //
                    // An important note in this scenario is that we have 
                    // already removed the telemetry from the queue.  If we don't 
                    // want to lose that, we should take action before throwing the
                    // exception to capture it.

                    if (eventBatch.Count == 0)
                    {
                        throw new Exception("There was an event too large to publish.");
                    }

                    await producer.SendAsync(eventBatch).ConfigureAwait(false);
                    totalEventCount += eventBatch.Count;

                    eventBatch.Dispose();
                    eventBatch = default;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                telemetryQueue.TryDequeue(out _);
            }
            
            // Once we hit this point, there were no telemetry items left
            // in the queue.  Send any that are held in the event batch.
            
            if ((eventBatch != default) && (eventBatch.Count > 0))
            {
                await producer.SendAsync(eventBatch).ConfigureAwait(false);
                totalEventCount += eventBatch.Count;

                eventBatch.Dispose();
                eventBatch = default;
            }            
            
            // Invoke the progress callback with the total count.
            
            progressCallback(totalEventCount);

            // Pause for the requested delay before attempting to 
            // pump the telemetry queue again.  

            try
            {
                await Task.Delay(interval, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException)
            {
               // Thrown if cancellation is requested while we're in the
               // delay.  This example is assuming that it isn't interesting 
               // to the application and swallows it.
            }
        }
    
    }, cancellationToken);
```

Which your application would interact with using something similar to:

```cs
// This is your master shutdown signal.  When you request
// cancellation on this token, all of your background tasks
// should terminate.

using var cancellationSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    
var producer = GetProducerClient();
var virtualThingsController = new VirtualThingsController();

try
{
    // Define a simple process callback.
    
    Action<int> progressCallback = totalCount => 
        Debug.WriteLine($"There have been a total of { totalCount } items published.");
        
    // Start the background processing and capture the tasks.  Once the
    // call is made, telemetry is being processed in the backgorund until
    // the cancellation token is signaled.
    
    var backgroundTasks = new List<Task>();
    
    backgroundTasks.Add
    (
        ProcessTruckTelemetry(
            producer, 
            virtualThingsController, 
            cancellationSource.Token, 
            progressCallback)
    );

    backgroundTasks.Add
    (
        ProcessOtherTelemetry(
            producer,
            virtualThingsController,
            cancellationSource.Token,
            progressCallback)
    );
    
    // The application can do whatever it normally does now.
    //
    //  << STUFF >>
    //
    
    // When the application is ready to stop, signal the cancellation
    // token and wait for the tasks.  We're not calling ConfigureAwait(false)
    // here because your application is WinForms, which has some 
    // sensitivity to the syncrhonization context.
    
    cancellationSource.Cancel();
    await Task.WhenAll(backgroundTasks);
}
finally
{        
    await producer.CloseAsync();
}
```

Comment: thanks heaps for your elaborate reply.  I am going to give it a try and let you know how I went. Thanks again!

Comment: Looking over the loop, I believe you will lose messages when the message wasn't too large to ever publish but was too large for the current batch because it was full. It is necessary to handle the case where a batch is full of items and the current item just needs to be added to a new batch.

Comment: Thanks, @DavidGarza.   You're right; we should have been using `TryPeek` and only dequeue after successful addition to the batch.   Updated.